# Windows 7 dual-boot Linux

Tags: filesystem, system-installation

I have a Windows 7 and I want to install Ubuntu. If i choose the option to install alongside with Windows 7, where's Ubuntu going to be installed. Is it going to be at my C: (System partition) or somewhere else?

P.S I have two partiotions C: System and D: Data (music, etc...)

Comment: If you don't have enough space for Ubuntu you will be able to chose on which partition you wish to install it, but it won't made any partition resize - installing Ubuntu will format whole partition. After installing Ubuntu you could use tools like GParted to manage your partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate hard drive partition will be created by you during installation for just Ubuntu, so it will not be on C or D in your case.

Comment: Tnx for the info , last question.Saying that it will create a separate partiotion from where will it get the data? Which volume will it shrink ?

Comment: You get to choose which one to shrink.  Make sure you use manual partitioning during the installation because if you use automatic, it will erase your whole hard drive and use it all for Ubuntu.

Comment: Alright that's what I needed to know. I wanted to install Ubuntu because I personally prefer it to Windows, because it more stable and efficient but I have a lot of data and I can't risk loosing it and I don't have the external drive to store it. Thanks for the info you've given me a lot of help and saved me a lot of time reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you select install with Windows, Ubuntu will be installed on Windows as a virtual machine, but you select "Install Ubuntu", you have to choose where you install Ubuntu as **"ext4"** format. You have three options

**1)** You can install Ubuntu on Windows and use it as a Virtual Machine
**2)** You can remove Windows and install Ubuntu as "ext4" format and save your datas and Music
**3)** You can remove your data and music, use **D:/** as Ubuntu and you have 2 OS **Windows and Ubuntu** and computer asks you whick OS you want to open when you open your computer.

**Maybe you want to look at it :** http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

And **Warning** these question was answered so many times and editors may be angry with you. You should research a lot and use **Google** Because you are not first computer's crazy installed Ubuntu with Windows for the first time :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm really sorry for asking such trivial questions that are already answered but it's more faster to ask. Thanks for the info you've given me :)

Comment: You are welcome. And Welcome to Ubuntu World :-)